# Passing char array to function and copying contents to another char array

Tags: c, char

I have a char array in which user input from the command line gets placed in. I want to pass that array to function `foo`and copy its content to a similar char array of the size of the contents contained in the original array. I am getting this warning however. Where am I going wrong?

```
char inputBuffer[500];

void foo(char *inputBuffer)
{
    char readBuffer[sizeof(inputBuffer)];
    strncpy(readBuffer, inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer));
}
```

> warning: argument to 'sizeof' in '__builtin_strncpy' call is the same
>   expression as the source, did you mean to provide an explicit length

Comment: For one thing, an array passed into a function decays to a pointer, so `sizeof` will not tell you the number of bytes in the buffer and instead tell you the size of the pointer.

Comment: @NickS Sorry, I typoed. It was in fact *inputBuffer already. Still getting the warning.

Comment: foo(inputBuffer);

Comment: I guess I can just assign the constant 500 to readBuffer as well...

Comment: If the size is needed you should pass it to the function as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the function `foo`, `inputBuffer` is a pointer to char, not an array.  Arrays and pointers are not the same.  One of the places this is apparent is the `sizeof` operator.

If you use the `sizeof` operator on a pointer, it will give you the size of a pointer (most likely 4 or 8), *not* the size of what it points to.

Note also that the function parameter `inputBuffer` masks the global variable of the same name.

Given that `inputBuffer` contains user input and is probably a string, you instead want to use `strlen` to get the length of the string.

```
void foo(char *inputBuffer)
{
    char readBuffer[strlen(inputBuffer) + 1];
    strcpy(readBuffer, inputBuffer);
    // do something with readBuffer
}
```

Note also that the size given to `readBuffer` contains an extra byte for the terminating null byte.

Comment: Does this code properly null-terminate the `readBuffer` variable?

Comment: [The docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) would suggest otherwise.

Comment: @orhtej2 You're correct, it will not in this case.  Changing to `strcpy`.